# Library in Android Studio - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-library, sticky-footer

i tried to use a library (https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1414) for a sticky header in a list view. I this configured well the library because i can use classes from there.
The code i'm using is like in the example from the link above, but i get a nullPointerExeption at ".build();"

This is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ViewGroup containerLayout ;
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    containerLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    String[] values = new String[]{"Android List View",
            "Adapter implementation",
            "Simple List View In Android",
            "Create List View Android",
            "Android Example",
            "List View Source Code",
            "List View Array Adapter",
            "Android Example List View",
    };


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     StikkyHeaderBuilder.stickTo(listView)
            .setHeader(R.id.header,containerLayout )
            .minHeightHeader(250)
             .animator(new IconAnimator())
            .build();

} }
```

And this is my error log:

> 08-14 15:10:57.188 32562-32562/com.example.cretucalinn.stickyheader1
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.example.cretucalinn.stickyheader1, PID: 32562
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.cretucalinn.stickyheader1/com.example.cretucalinn.stickyheader1.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at
>   it.carlom.stikkyheader.core.StikkyHeader.disallowTouchBehindHeader(StikkyHeader.java:47)
>                                                                                              at
>   it.carlom.stikkyheader.core.StikkyHeader.build(StikkyHeader.java:38)
>                                                                                              at
>   it.carlom.stikkyheader.core.StikkyHeaderBuilder$ListViewBuilder.build(StikkyHeaderBuilder.java:113)
>                                                                                              at
>   it.carlom.stikkyheader.core.StikkyHeaderBuilder$ListViewBuilder.build(StikkyHeaderBuilder.java:95)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.example.cretucalinn.stickyheader1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: That looks more like a runtime error than a compilation error to me... have your tried a VS restart or a  computer reboot? Seems like some file is locked.

Comment: This looks more like a VS bug or a filesystem space or permissions issue, irrelevant of code. Replace all your code with `int main() {}` and see if that compiles. Maybe the `+` characters in the path (`E:\C++`)  might be an issue.